# Error with emmeans function in R . How to fix it?

Tags: r, emmeans

I have a file like this :

[image]

I am using this data set to predict a linear mixed model and the I want to use the function `emmeans` in order to calculate the estimated means for my conditions. The code that I am using is here :

```
newtab5 <- read.csv(file="sliding_LMM_test.csv", header=T, sep=",")
head(newtab5)

library(lmerTest)

model <- lmer(formula = data1 ~ flabel + (1 | whichFragments), data = newtab5, control=lmerControl(check.nlev.gtr.1 = "ignore"))
sfit <-summary(model)
sfit$coefficients[,2][2]
sfit$coefficients[,5][2]

library(emmeans)

means <- emmeans(model, "flabel")
test<-summary(means)
```

And I have this error:

```
>  Error in t(ZZ) %*% EE :Cholmod error 'X and/or Y have wrong dimensions' at file ../MatrixOps/cholmod_sdmult.c, line 90
```

It looks like the `emmeans` function does not work when the which fragments column has the same values.

Do you know any way to skip this or to make `emmeans` to work for that case ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example that produces this error?

Comment: The table i have is an example that produces this error ! do you want something else ?

Comment: It depends on whether you want me to try to reproduce this condition on my own pc and to try to figure out what’s going wrong. If you do, post the data (or some other dataset that leads to this error) here somehow, or email it to the maintainer of emmeans.

Comment: `flabel <- c('con1','con1','con1', 'con2','con2','con2') 
sample  <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)  
whichFragments <- c('chr1_1','chr1_1','chr1_1', 'chr1_1', 'chr1_1', 'chr1_1') 
data1 <- c(0.99, 0.42, 0.3873, 0.244, 0.005, 0.0726)
data <- data.frame(flabel, sample, whichFragments, data1)
library(lmerTest)
library(emmeans)
model <- lmer(formula = data1 ~ flabel + (1 | whichFragments), data = data, control=lmerControl(check.nlev.gtr.1 = "ignore"))
sfit <-summary(model)
means <- emmeans(model, "flabel")`   this code is working and produces the error. You can run it on your computer

Comment: Sorry I didn’t realize that was the whole dataset, thought it was the first few observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an error that comes up in the **pbkrtest** package, in the computation of the adjusted covariance matrix needed for the Kenward-Roger degrees of freedom (which is the default degrees-of-freedom method for `lmerMod` objects). Almost certainly this is related to the undisclosed warning message encountered when fitting the model:

```
> model <- lmer(formula = data1 ~ flabel + (1 | whichFragments), 
+    data = data, control=lmerControl(check.nlev.gtr.1 = "ignore")) 
Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
   Hessian is numerically singular: parameters are not uniquely determined
```

Surprisingly (to me), you can still get results if you use some other d.f. method, e.g. Satterthwaite:

```
> emmeans(model, "flabel", mode = "satterth")
 flabel emmean    SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 con1    0.599 0.147 0.26    -3879     3880
 con2    0.107 0.147 0.26    -3880     3880

Degrees-of-freedom method: satterthwaite 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Having 0.26 degrees of freedom isn't much: look at the CIs.

Just as a general observation, you are always asking for trouble when you try to estimate a variance with only one observation. That is what this model tries to do, in terms of the between-`whichFragments` variance. I sure hope you have more data than this in your real research.

By the way, if all you want is the means, you can just compute the means:

```
> with(data, tapply(data1, flabel, mean))

  con1   con2 
0.5991 0.1072
```

Comment: Thats true this is not all my data this is a part of some cases in my data. In most of the cases i have more data from different areas so the the whichFragments column differs, but there are some few cases like above . I was thinking to calculate normal means in cases like this and  Estimated Marginal Means in cases with more data. As i can see the the estimated means are not different with the normal means in that case .

Comment: I suggest you fit the full model with `case` included as a factor, then get all the EMMs via `emmeans(model, ~ flabel | case)`. This will produce estimates even in those cases with one fragment.

Comment: What do you mean by case ?

Comment: Whatever you meant by it when you said “in some cases...”  I was thinking there must be a factor associated with that. Location? Subject? Day?

Comment: No, i was talking about cases of more data ! The columns are always like this ! What is the difference of satterth mode instead of normal ?

Comment: Ok in that case I think you may be trying to be too fancy with these analyses. Maybe it’d be better to just calculate ordinary sample means in each dataset.

Comment: This is what i did first and i calculated ordinary means..but i wanted to try the estimated as well .